# Django: objects are not showing at index page

Tags: django

This is my first project with Django and I got a problem. In the backend I created news, but I have an issue displaying the news on the frontpage. Models should be fine since I can create news into the admin panel. But I can't figure out where is my mistake.

I have app 'pages'>views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from mainnews.models import Mainnews

# Create your views here.
def home_view(request):
    main = Mainnews.objects.all()

    context = {
        'main' : main
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

root>urls.py

```
from pages.views import home_view
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_view, name = 'home'),
]
```

and app mainnews>views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Mainnews
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    main = Mainnews.objects.all()
    context = {
        'main' : main
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and the template mainnewsandevents.html that extends to index

```
{% block content %}
  <!-- Section 2 News and Events -->
  <div id="news-container">
    <div class="jumbo-news">
        <img id = 'jumboImgUrl' class='jumbo-img' src="{{ main.image.url }}">
        <h2 id = 'jumboTitle' class='jumbo-title'>{{ main.title }}</h2>
        <h4 id = 'jumboDescription' class='jumbo-parag'>{{ main.description }}</h4>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it like this:

```
def home_view(request):
    main = Mainnews.objects.first()
    # or main = Mainnews.objects.last()
    # other code
```

or if you need to show all objects on your template use something like it:

```
{% block content %}
  <!-- Section 2 News and Events -->
  <div id="news-container">
    <div class="jumbo-news">
        {% for article in main %}
            <img id = 'jumboImgUrl' class='jumbo-img' src="{{ main.image.url }}">
            <h2 id = 'jumboTitle' class='jumbo-title'>{{ main.title }}</h2>
            <h4 id = 'jumboDescription' class='jumbo-parag'>{{ main.description }}</h4>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Depends on your needs. 
Also you shouldn't use not obvious names for variables so you shall use main_news instead of main.

Answer (score 1):

**main is an array of objects right so you need a for loop to get every object**

```
{% block content %}
  <!-- Section 2 News and Events -->
  <div id="news-container">
    <div class="jumbo-news">
        {% for obj in main %}
            <img id = 'jumboImgUrl' class='jumbo-img' src={{ obj.image.url }}>
            <h2 id = 'jumboTitle' class='jumbo-title'>{{ obj.title }}</h2>
            <h4 id = 'jumboDescription' class='jumbo-parag'>{{ obj.description }}</h4>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```